# URL parameters also show on all the anchor tags links

Tags: html, wordpress, url, anchor

I am using UTM parameters in the URL. Below is an example

https://sandbox.xyz.co/test-form?utm_source=linkedin&utm_medium=testcampaign

Whenever I am using the above URL then above UTM fields are shown to all the anchor tags automatically.

for example, I am using the above URL then my anchor tags are shown like

```
<a href="https://sandbox.xyz.co/home?utm_source=linkedin&utm_medium=testcampaign">Home</a>
<a href=https://sandbox.xyz.co/about-us?utm_source=linkedin&utm_medium=testcampaign"">About uS</a>
```

I had to try disabling all the plugins and changing the themes but I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: So you have /home in the href and your site fills it with the parameters? That must be a setting or a plugin. It is not default on as far as I can find

Comment: @mplungjan, I have disabled all the plugins, but sill showing the same.. I have changed the theme as well but the same issue..

Comment: @mplungjan, I have right-clicked on the page and viewed the source and tried to find the <base href= but not getting it.

Comment: So every url of every link in the page in view source is `https://yourserver.com/....?searchparametersOfCurrentPage`?

Comment: Do these parameters appear in the HTML source, or the "generated source" of the page (ie. by JavaScript)?

Comment: _Aside:_ @mplungjan "searchparametersOfCurrentPage" - These are analytics tracking params, not "search params"? What does the `base` element have to do with this? That would not result in URL parameters being appended to other links on the page?

Comment: I've removed the `.htaccess` tag since that would seem to be irrelevant here.

Comment: @MrWhite, UTM parameters are not showing in the view source code.

Comment: Then they are being added by client-side JavaScript... by your analytics software / Google Analytics. (?)

Comment: @MrWhite, I am using a salient wordpress theme. I have checked Google Analytics. Can you help me with how it's adding UTM using Google Analytics so that I can check that setting?

Comment: @MrWhite, I have changed the theme 2024 and I am getting the same issue in this also..